# Undefined variable: date on Line 81

Tags: variables, undefined, php

I am having trouble once again with the undefined variable errors within my PHP file. The error (date) is occurring on line 81 in the PHP file, and I am not sure exactly why this error will not subside. This program is supposed to allow a user to enter an IP address and current date in the 111.222.3.44 and mm/dd/yyyy formats. Could someone point out the issue here?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Displaying Errors</title>
</head>
<body>


<?php
    $IP = '/^\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d\.\d{2}$/';
    $number = '/^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})$/';

    if (isset($_POST["IP"])) {$IP = $_POST["IP"];}
    if (isset($_POST["date"])) {$date = $_POST["date"];}

if (preg_match('/^\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d\.\d{2}$/' , $IP)) 
    { 
        print "Your IP address is good."; 

            if (preg_match('/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/', $date))
                { 
                    print "The date format is ok. Thank you for submitting your form<br>."; 
                }
            else if ($date = " ")
    { 
?>

        <form method="GET" method="Lab 10.php" >
        <h1></h1>
        <p>
        IP Address
        <input type="text" name="ip" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['IP']; ?>"/><br />
        <p style="color:red;">Enter the date mm/dd/yy</p>
        <input type="text" name="date" value="

        <?php echo $_REQUEST['date']; ?>" /><br />


        <br /><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <?php 

        print "<font color=\"red\">The date is empty<br></font>";
        print "<font color=\"red\">You need to resubmit the form</font>";


    }

    else
    {


        ?><form method="GET" method="Lab 10.php" >
        <h1></h1>
        <p>
        IP Address
        <input type="text" name="IP" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['IP']; ?>"/><br />
        <p style="color:red;">Enter the date mm/dd/yy</p>
         <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['date']; ?>" /><br />


        <br /><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <?php

        print "<font color=\"red\">The date format is incorrect<br></font>";
        print "<font color=\"red\">You need to resubmit the form</font>";
    }
}

else if ($IP = " ") //test if ip address is null
{
    print "<font color =\"red\">The IP Address is empty.</font><br>";




    if (preg_match('/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/', $date))
        { 
            print "The date format is ok. Thank you for submitting your form<br>."; 
        }
           else if ($date = " ")
        { 


        ?><form method="GET" method="Lab 10.php" >
        <h1></h1>
        <p>
        IP Address
        <input type="text" name="ip" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['IP']; ?>"/><br />
        <p style="color:red;">Enter the date mm/dd/yy</p>
        <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['date']; ?>" /><br />


        <br /><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <?php 
        print "<font color=\"red\">The date is empty<br></font>";
        print "<font color=\"red\">You need to resubmit the form</font>";



        }

    else
        {


        ?><form method="GET" method="Lab 10.php" >
        <h1></h1>
        <p>
        IP Address
        <input type="text" name="ip" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['IP']; ?>"/><br />
        <p style="color:red;">Enter the date mm/dd/yy</p>
        <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['date']; ?>" /><br />


        <br /><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <?php

        print "<font color=\"red\">The date format is incorrect<br></font>";
        print "<font color=\"red\">You need to resubmit the form</font>";
        }

}


    else //if IP is anything else but accepted
{ 
    print "<font color=\"red\">Please enter a valid IP address.</font><br>"; 



    if (preg_match('/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/', $date))
        { 
        print "The date format is ok. Thank you for submitting your form<br>."; 


        }


            else if ($date = " ")
        { 
        print "The date is empty<br>";
        print "You need to resubmit the form<br>";

        ?><form method="GET" method="Lab 10.php" >
        <h1></h1>
        <p>
        IP Address
        <input type="text" name="ip" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['IP']; ?>"/><br />
        <p style="color:red;">Enter the date mm/dd/yy</p>
        <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['date']; ?>" /><br />


        <br /><br />

         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <?php 
        print "<font color=\"red\">The date is empty<br></font>";
        print "<font color=\"red\">You need to resubmit the form</font>";




        }

    else
        {
        print "The date format is incorrect<br>";
        print "You need to resubmit the form<br>";

        ?><form method="GET" method="Lab 10.php" >
        <h1></h1>
        <p>
        IP Address
         <input type="text" name="ip" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['IP']; ?>"/><br />
        <p style="color:red;">Enter the date mm/dd/yy</p>
        <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['date']; ?>" /><br />


        <br /><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <?php
print "<font color=\"red\">The date format is incorrect<br></font>";
        print "<font color=\"red\">You need to resubmit the form</font>";
        }

}







?>
```

Comment: Please don't dump your entire code here and expect us to solve it for you. Isolate your error. Print out your variables before and after you manipulate them.

Comment: I was not expecting anyone to simply solve my problem and give me the correct solution, but to guide me in the right direction. I am new to stackoverflow, so do not just expect me to know how to use the site correctly...

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
if (isset($_POST["date"])) {$date = $_POST["date"];}
```

You're only setting `$date` if it's in the `$_POST` array, but your form method is `GET`